Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3 never selects the http2 over http
I have created the below .net server with multiple listeners over multiple ports and each with specific http port and http protocol configuration
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configure Kestrel for h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS)
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    // Listen on port 5000 for h2c (HTTP/2 without TLS)
    options.ListenAnyIP(5000, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; // Only HTTP/2 Cleartext (h2c)
    });

    // Optionally, listen on port 5001 for HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 with TLS
    options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(); // HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 with TLS
    });

    // Optionally, listen on port 5002 for HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 with TLS
    options.ListenAnyIP(5002, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(); // HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 with TLS
    });

    options.ListenAnyIP(5003, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
    });


    options.ListenAnyIP(5004, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
    });

    options.ListenAnyIP(5005, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http3;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(); // HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 with TLS
    });

    options.ListenAnyIP(5006, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(); // HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 with TLS
    });

    options.ListenAnyIP(5007, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
        listenOptions.UseHttps(); // HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 with TLS
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    // Check if the request is using HTTP/2 (h2c)
    if (context.Request.Protocol == "HTTP/2")
    {
        return Results.Text("Hello from HTTP/2");
    }

    // Check if the request is using HTTP/2 (h2c)
    if (context.Request.Protocol == "HTTP/3")
    {
        return Results.Text("Hello from HTTP/3");
    }

    return Results.Text("Hello from HTTP/1.x or HTTPS");
});

app.Run();

The below listener I was expecting to accept connection over http2 if I specify from the client to send to connect with http2 or higher only (the policy is RequestVersionOrHigher) but unexpectedly I am getting the follwoing error An error occurred: The HTTP/2 server closed the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED' (0xd). (HttpProtocolError)
    options.ListenAnyIP(5004, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
    });


Enter the server port (default is 5004): 5004
Enter Schema: (http, https): http
Select the HTTP version:
1 - HTTP/1.1
2 - HTTP/2
3 - HTTP/3 (if supported)
2
Select the HTTP version policy:
1 - RequestVersionExact (forces the request to use the specified HTTP version)
2 - RequestVersionOrHigher (tries the specified version or higher if supported)
3 - RequestVersionOrLower (tries the specified version or lower if necessary)
2
Do you want to include the Upgrade header for h2c? (yes/no): no
Request Headers:
An error occurred: The HTTP/2 server closed the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED' (0xd). (HttpProtocolError)


Below is my httpclient if you want to use for testing and above were my choices
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userInput;
        do
        {
            // Prompt the user to specify the port number
            Console.Write("Enter the server port (default is 5004): ");
            string portInput = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
            int port = string.IsNullOrEmpty(portInput) ? 5004 : int.Parse(portInput);

            Console.Write("Enter Schema: (http, https): ");
            string? schema = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();

            // Prompt the user to specify the HTTP version
            Console.WriteLine("Select the HTTP version:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - HTTP/1.1");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - HTTP/2");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - HTTP/3 (if supported)");

            Version httpVersion = new Version(2, 0); // Default to HTTP/2
            string versionInput = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
            switch (versionInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    httpVersion = new Version(1, 1);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    httpVersion = new Version(2, 0);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    httpVersion = new Version(3, 0); // Only if HTTP/3 is supported
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection, using default: HTTP/2.");
                    break;
            }

            // Prompt the user to specify the HttpVersionPolicy
            Console.WriteLine("Select the HTTP version policy:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - RequestVersionExact (forces the request to use the specified HTTP version)");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - RequestVersionOrHigher (tries the specified version or higher if supported)");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - RequestVersionOrLower (tries the specified version or lower if necessary)");

            HttpVersionPolicy versionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrLower; // Default policy
            string policyInput = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
            switch (policyInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    versionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    versionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrHigher;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    versionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrLower;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection, using default: RequestVersionOrLower.");
                    break;
            }

            // Ask the user if they want to include the Upgrade header for HTTP/2 cleartext (h2c)
            bool includeUpgradeHeader = false;
            if (httpVersion == new Version(2, 0) && schema == "http")
            {
                Console.Write("Do you want to include the Upgrade header for h2c? (yes/no): ");
                string? upgradeHeaderInput = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim().ToLower();
                includeUpgradeHeader = (upgradeHeaderInput == "yes");
            }

            // Create a SocketsHttpHandler and configure it for HTTP/2 Cleartext (h2c)
            var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                // Disable SSL/TLS (Cleartext connection)
                SslOptions = { RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true }
            };

            // Set up HttpClient with the handler
            using var client = new HttpClient(handler);

            try
            {
                // Configure the request URL based on the specified port
                string url = $"{schema ?? "http"}://localhost:{port}/";

                // Configure the request to use the user-specified HTTP version
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)
                {
                    Version = httpVersion, // Use the HTTP version specified by the user
                    VersionPolicy = versionPolicy  // Use the policy specified by the user
                };

                // Add the Upgrade header for HTTP/2 cleartext (h2c) if the user chooses to
                if (includeUpgradeHeader)
                {
                    request.Headers.Connection.Add("Upgrade");
                    request.Headers.Upgrade.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductHeaderValue("h2"));
                    // Base64url-encoded empty SETTINGS frame for HTTP/2. (An actual encoded frame would be used in real apps)
                    request.Headers.Add("HTTP2-Settings", "AAMAAABkAAQAAP__");
                }

                // Print request headers
                Console.WriteLine("Request Headers:");
                foreach (var header in request.Headers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}");
                }

                // Send the request
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Read the response content
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Output the response status and content
                Console.WriteLine($"\nStatus Code: {response.StatusCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\nResponse Headers: {response.Headers} {response.Content.Headers}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Response: {content}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.Write("Enter 'exit' to quit or press Enter to send a request: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
        } while (userInput?.ToLower() != "exit");
    }
}

Why is the http 1_1 required for the connection over http?
If I use https all works fine!
If I chose RequestVersionOrLower it will automatically default to http 1.1 so if that is the case, then what is the benefit of settomg         listenOptions.Protocols to HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3 if it will always default to http 1.1 over http?
Is this a limitation?

AFAIK HTTP/2`` requires https so without that http/1.1 is required.

Well, http2 supports http 2 over clear text but that only works if you strictly listen only for http2 as below (prenegotiated clear text connection) but not on-fly negotiation using the connection:upgrade header. Looks like any option that would requires negotiation, it must be https as it seems that .net only supports negotiation over TLS  ALPN (H2) or advertised via Alt-Svc (H3).
options.ListenAnyIP(5000, listenOptions =>
{
    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; // Only HTTP/2 Cleartext (h2c)
});


Yeah, in .Net I think my statement is correct, so you're probably on your own here. I also think many servers will refuse to it.
